# How to inspect clients that are connected to a GRPC server

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

To provide better debugging information for my GRPC server/client setup, I am trying to find an API for `grpc.server` that allows me to inspect what clients are connected to the server.

The most promising question I have found is [question, which gives a starting point on how to do this in Java GRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515454/1333978). However, the Java API doesn't exist in the Python GRPC implementation.

So far, I keep track of unique peers using the `context.peer()` method in a `grpc.ServicerContext`. If a peer hasn't sent a request in a while (a timeout I set to 2 seconds) I assume the client has disconnected.

I've started looking at the python-grpc source code but I haven't made any headway.

If anyone knows of a similar API in python I could use, that would be appreciated! Even an internal API would be sufficient for these debugging needs.

Comment: Does https://grpc.io/blog/a_short_introduction_to_channelz/ work for your requirement?

Comment: @ZhouyihaiDing this is my most promising lead, but when I was doing the research I could find almost nothing about the python API for channelz, and the source code on https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_channelz.html was not very informative. It seems that if I install the pip package `grpc-channelz`, then I'll be able to pull channelz statistics from "C-Core", but there is no documentation or examples as to how to do this programmatically in Python. Although if someone _does_ have this documentation, I would love to discuss it in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some more documentation and examples of channelz, other people have been suggesting it and it seems like what you want.

Here's a [pull request that gives an example of channelz being used](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/19310/files). It only uses the GetServer channelz API, so you'll have to adapt it.

And here's a [unit test that uses channelz](https://github.com/lidizheng/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/channelz/_channelz_servicer_test.py),
which tests APIs that are probably relevant GetTopChannels API.

Comment: Thank you! This has what I was looking for! Richard and Zhouyihai both suggested channelz, but these examples allowed me to figure out a solution. I'll edit this answer with some code.

Comment: I haven't been able to edit in a code sample of a channelz solution since my edit was rejected, but I was able to access channelz statistics of a GRPC server in the same process by just copying and pasting the stub implementations of, say, `GetServerSockets` from https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/_modules/grpc_channelz/v1/channelz.html#ChannelzServicer. Specifically, accessing `grpc._cython.cygrpc.channelz_get_server_sockets` will return an protobuf representing server sockets connected to clients.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a native API for this, but you have all of the pieces you need. Here's a modified version of the `helloworld` example from the repo.

```py
class PeerSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._peers_lock = threading.RLock()
        self._peers = {}

    def connect(self, peer):
        print("Peer {} connecting".format(peer))
        with self._peers_lock:
            if peer not in self._peers:
                self._peers[peer] = 1
            else:
                self._peers[peer] += 1

    def disconnect(self, peer):
        print("Peer {} disconnecting".format(peer))
        with self._peers_lock:
            if peer not in self._peers:
                raise RuntimeError("Tried to disconnect peer '{}' but it was never connected.".format(peer))
            self._peers[peer] -= 1
            if self._peers[peer] == 0:
                del self._peers[peer]

    def peers(self):
        with self._peers_lock:
            return self._peers.keys()


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def __init__(self):
        self._peer_set = PeerSet()

    def _record_peer(self, context):
        def _unregister_peer():
            self._peer_set.disconnect(context.peer())
        context.add_callback(_unregister_peer)
        self._peer_set.connect(context.peer())

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        self._record_peer(context)
        for i in range(10):
            print("[thread {}] Peers: {}".format(threading.currentThread().ident, self._peer_set.peers()))
            time.sleep(1)
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
```

This will get you output like the following:

```
[thread 139905506195200] Peers: [u'ipv6:[::1]:57940', u'ipv6:[::1]:57930', u'ipv6:[::1]:57926', u'ipv6:[::1]:57920', u'ipv6:[::1]:57934']
```

As Ding commented above, [channelz](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-channelz/) may also be a good fit for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample Richard! I'm already using `context.peer()` as you have suggested, but this only keeps track of _currently-executing RPCs_, not active channels in both my code and your solution. Apologies for not clarifying my `context.peer()` solution. `channelz` _would_ work, but I can find almost no documentation on its python APIs as per my reply to Ding (specifically, how to read channelz statistics from the "C-Core" in Python). If there are no other public Python channelz docs, I'll just hack in a long-lived "heartbeat" RPC to detect when a channel closes from the server side.

Answer (score 1):

There is one tool [grpcdebug](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpcdebug), it could inspect clients that are connected to a GRPC server.

> grpcdebug is a command line interface focusing on simplifying the debugging process of gRPC applications. grpcdebug fetches the internal states of the gRPC library from the application via gRPC protocol and provide a human-friendly UX to browse them. Currently, it supports Channelz/Health Checking/CSDS (aka. admin services)

```
grpcdebug is an gRPC service admin CLI

Usage:
  grpcdebug <target address> [flags] <command>

Available Commands:
  channelz    Display gRPC states in human readable way.
  health      Check health status of the target service (default "").
  help        Help about any command
  xds         Fetch xDS related information.
```