# How to make each client get their state if there is class instance in grpc-python server side?

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc, grpc-python

I want to use grpc-python in the following scenario, but I don' t know how to realize it.

The scenario is that, in the python server, it uses class to calculate and update the instance' s state, then sends such state to corresponding client; in the client side, more than one clients need to communicate with the server to get its one result and not interfered by others.

Specifically, suppose there is a class with initial value self.i =0, then each time the client calls the class' s update function, it does self.i=self.i+1 and returns self.i. Actually there are two clients call such update function simultaneously, like when client1 calls update at third time, client2 calls update at first time.

I think this may can be solved by creating thread for each client to avoid conflict. If the new client calls, new thead will be created; if existing client calls, existing thread will be used. But I don' t know how to realize it?

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Adding threads isn't going to simplify things but rather complicate them. For what do you need independent threads? If two clients make a call at the same time, just process them one after the other.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this problem by myself. If you have any other better solutions, you can post here.

I edited helloworld example in grpc-python introduction to explain my aim.

For helloworld.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  rpc Unsubscribe (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I add Unsubsribe function to allow one specific client to diconnect from server.

In hello_server.py

```
import grpc
import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc
import threading
from threading import RLock
import time
from concurrent import futures
import logging


class Calcuate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def add(self):
        self.i+=1
        return self.i


class PeerSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._peers_lock = RLock()
        self._peers = {}
        self.instances = {}

    def connect(self, peer):
        with self._peers_lock:
            if peer not in self._peers:
                print("Peer {} connecting".format(peer))
                self._peers[peer] = 1
                a = Calcuate()
                self.instances[peer] = a
                output = a.add()
                return output
            else:
                self._peers[peer] += 1
                a = self.instances[peer]
                output = a.add()
                return output


    def disconnect(self, peer):
        print("Peer {} disconnecting".format(peer))
        with self._peers_lock:
            if peer not in self._peers:
                raise RuntimeError("Tried to disconnect peer '{}' but it was never connected.".format(peer))
            del self._peers[peer]
            del self.instances[peer]

    def peers(self):
        with self._peers_lock:
            return self._peers.keys()


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def __init__(self):
        self._peer_set = PeerSet()

    def _record_peer(self, context):
        return self._peer_set.connect(context.peer())

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        output = self._record_peer(context)
        print("[thread {}] Peers: {}, output: {}".format(threading.currentThread().ident, self._peer_set.peers(), output))
        time.sleep(1)
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, {}, {}!'.format(request.name, output))

    def Unsubscribe(self, request, context):
        self._peer_set.disconnect(context.peer())
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='{} disconnected!'.format(context.peer()))



def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    serve()
```

The use of context.peer() is adapted from Richard Belleville' s answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228886/how-to-inspect-clients-that-are-connected-to-a-grpc-server/57317444#57317444). You can change add() function to any other functions that can be used to update instance' s state.

In hello_client.py

```
from __future__ import print_function

import logging

import grpc
import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


def run():
    # NOTE(gRPC Python Team): .close() is possible on a channel and should be
    # used in circumstances in which the with statement does not fit the needs
    # of the code.
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
        print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='Tom'))
        print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='Jerry'))
        print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
        stub.Unsubscribe(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name="end"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    run()
```

If we run serveral hello_client.py simultaneously, the server can distinguish the different clients and send correct corresponding info to them.